# How can I add two labels to a StackLayout template in C#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have checked the [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout?view=xamarin-forms) for StackLayout but it doesn't seem to help me.  Here's what I have:

```
public class PracticeButtons : StackLayout
{
    public PracticeButtons()
    {
        Children = { new Label() { Text = "ABC" }; }

    }
}
```

I thought this would work according to the docs but it seems not to work at all.

Can someone advise me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children is an `IList<View>` you need to add labels or any other views to the list like any other IEnumerable object

```
public class PracticeButtons : StackLayout
{
   public PracticeButtons()
   {
      Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Label 1" });
      Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Label 2" });
   }
}
```